# Firebase App Indexing for iOS: no app icon in search results

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-app-indexing

I've just finished implementing app indexing in one of my apps.
I followed Google's instructions [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-indexing/ios/app) and everything seems to work, except that I do not see the app icon in the search result list.

When I perform a Google search in Safari, it just shows the usual search result list. Has anyone experience with this?

Google docs say:

> The app icon appears in the Search results list some time after the initial click through from Search results.

Does anyone know what this is exactly suppose to mean? Do I have to have a touch icon or similar in place on the web server? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

It means you'll need to click through an actual link you've indexed/found in Search and successfully load the link. Once you've done that it'll probably take a few hours for the App Icon to then show up.

Answer (score 1):

It's so sad to tell, but App indexing for iOS is no longer active.

You won't see app icons on SERPs, nor get ranking boost.
You can still launch apps from SERPs, but it owes to universal links.

A JP Googler announced it...

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmaster-ja/2fB6nv_bTq4

and doc is updated.

"**The App Indexing API on Android** enhances ranking performance for links to your app and provides autocomplete suggestions based on user actions you log in your app."
https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-indexing/